# Make Magento search more effective? Is there a way to make it search for product names first?

Tags: search, catalogsearch

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

When we do a search for a word which is also contained in product names - it returns all kinds of products but does not show the products that actually have that word in their product names first.

**What is the best way to make the Search look for products that contain the search for word first?**

My settings are as follows:

```
Catalog Search
Minimal Query Length = 1
Maximum Query Length = 128
Maximum Query Words Count = 10
Search type = Combine (Like and Fulltext)
Apply Layered Navigation if Search Results are Less Than: 2000
```

**I wouldn't mind installing an extension if it improves the search results.**

Comment: There is a lot of extension to make Magento search better , here is our digest of best M1 solutions https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-best-magento-extensions-for-improved-catalog-search.html For the best results you should consider use Sphinx or Elasticsearch as search engine